# WP REST API v2 Can't use filters

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce-rest-api

I Connecting with woocommerse with Oauth2.

But i can't use filters, example  `/wp-json/wp/v2/post&filter[category_name]=food`

I  get information about users, example `http://my-site/wp-json/wp/v2/users`, but on page i get info about first 10 users, i need more... When i use filter, example : `http://my-site/wp-json/wp/v2/users?filter[posts_per_page]=5`- filter not work

my code:

```
require('vendor/autoload.php');
const CLIENT_ID     = 'my-ID';
const CLIENT_SECRET = 'my-secret';
const REDIRECT_URI           = 'http://wooc/test.php';
const AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT = 'http://my-site/oauth/authorize';
const TOKEN_ENDPOINT         = 'http://my-site/oauth/token';

$client = new OAuth2\Client(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);
if (!isset($_GET['code']))
{
 $auth_url = $client->getAuthenticationUrl(AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT, REDIRECT_URI);
header('Location: ' . $auth_url);
die('Redirect');
}
else
{
$params = array('code' => $_GET['code'], 'redirect_uri' => REDIRECT_URI);
$response = $client->getAccessToken(TOKEN_ENDPOINT, 'authorization_code',$params);
}
$client->setAccessToken("a6kpdxqqs3runou66ovzjjy54rvfubv64hhpdomn");
$data = $client->fetch("http://my-site/wp-json/wp/v2/users?filter[posts_per_page]=5");
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($data);
```

I do not understand where the error!
Please help. thank you

Answer (score 2):

The API response filtering functionality has been superseded by more robust query parameters like ?categories=, ?slug= and ?per_page=.

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress 4.7 the filter argument for any post endpoint was removed, The filter argument allows the posts to be filtered using WP_Query public query vars. This plugin restores the filter parameter for sites that were previously using it: https://github.com/luisfredgs/rest-filter

However, you can also convert your existing code to remove `filter`.

Something along the lines of this:

```
http://my-site/wp-json/wp/v2/users?filter[posts_per_page]=5
```

becomes this:

```
http://my-site/wp-json/wp/v2/users?posts_per_page=5
```

Comment: I found this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-filter/ is better than the one linked and has built-in ACF support.

Comment: This plugin has been closed as of July 13, 2021 and is not available for download. Reason: Guideline Violation. :(